# JSP: Why does this conditional work?

Tags: java, jsp

I am an admitted JSP (and Java) rookie. I have this piece of code that works:

```
String pageMessageStart = "<div id=\"messageBox\" class=\"center\">";
String pageMessage = "";
String pageMessageEnd = "</div>";

 if(request.getParameter("message") != null) {
  pageMessage = pageMessageStart;
  /* Certain messages will come in as an alias. Let's make user-friendly messages with them */
  if(request.getParameter("message").equals("invalidsession"))
    pageMessage += "Session expired; you have been automatically logged out.";
  else if(request.getParameter("message").equals("NOCOOKIE"))
    pageMessage += "No valid cookie found; you must have cookies enabled to use this application.";
  else if(request.getParameter("message").equals("invalidcredentials"))
    pageMessage += "Incorrect username and/or password.";
  else if(request.getParameter("message").equals("LICENSE_CHANGED"))
    pageMessage += "Your license key has been successfully applied.";
  else
  /* If there is no alias but there is still a message, let's just display it verbatim */
  pageMessage += request.getParameter("message");

  pageMessage += pageMessageEnd;
};
```

The string is later `out.println`'d to a spot in the main HTML area.

What I don't understand is why `!= null` in the conditional works. Or more to the point: does it only have the APPEARANCE of working? My very rookie understanding is that the `.equals()` method is the way to go; in fact, my nested conditionals use `.equals()` as you can see. I thought the line should be:

```
if(!request.getParameter("message").equals("null") {}
/* or this one */
if(!request.getParameter("message").equals(null) {}
```

With my limited understanding, all I can guess is that when that parameter is null, there's no string and .equals() is a comparison method for strings. It just seems discrepant that I use a method when looking for a positive match, but an operator when looking for a negative match. I'm worried that the != that I'm using is bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being able to invoke `equals()` on a method requires that the reference is **not** `null`. It would otherwise result in a `NullPointerException` (simply because `null` doesn't refer/point to anything which has an `equals()` method). Hence the `obj != null` instead of `obj.equals(null)` test.

```
Object object = null;

if (object.equals(null)) { // NullPointerException! object is null.
    // ...
}
```

That using `!=` or `==` is by you interpreted as a "bad practice" is perhaps caused by the confusion that you shouldn't compare `String`'s contents by those operators, but rather by `equals()`. Comparing `String`s by `==` would only compare if they both points to the same reference, not if they have both the same content (internal object value).

```
String s1 = "foo";
String s2 = new String("foo");
String s3 = s2;

System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false
System.out.println(s1 == s3); // false
System.out.println(s2 == s3); // true

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // true
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3)); // true
System.out.println(s2.equals(s3)); // true
```

`String`s are namely objects, not primitives. The `!=` and `==` would only give the expected result on primitives like `int,`long`, etc.

This has by the way nothing to do with JSPs. It's just basic Java. Writing Java code incorrectly in a JSP file instead of a Java class and having problems with the Java code doesn't make it a JSP problem. You would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class.

Comment: Agreed; the "(and Java)" perhaps didn't stress that enough. Since I'm only writing Java within the context of a JSP, that influenced the title and tag. Thanks very much for taking time to clarify; I understand that it's a basic question hardly worth your time. ;-)

Comment: Additional question if you don't mind: if I later have a conditional checking for a different parameter in the query string, but this time looking for a positive match, is it good practice to check for the existence of the parameter first? After all, without the parameter there, the conditional will still (correctly) fail so an extra check seems redundant.

Comment: You should **always** check if the parameter is present by testing against `null`. Never trust user input and expect that the parameter is always supplied. HTTP requests can easily be hacked/tampered by tools.

Answer (score 1):

1. This looks like pure Java.  Do you really have this huge scriptlet embedded in a JSP ?  If so, that's pretty ugly.
2. `request.getParameter("message")` returns a null value if the web request did not contain a `message` parameter.  The `null` value is not a `String`.  You need to understand the difference between comparing objects for equality via `==` and comparing their values via `equals()`
3. That switch statement is pretty ugly too.  You should be fetching these strings from a properties file via a `fmt:message` tag.  Build the message key by appending the "message" parameter to some prefix:

   <fmt:message key="error.${message}">

You can reduce all this code to about five lines in a JSP:

```
<c:if test="${message}">
  <div id="messageBox" class="center">
    <fmt:message key="error.${message}">
  </div>
</c:if>
```

This all assumes you are using a recent version of Java EE.

Also, if you have control over both the JSP and the CSS, do not use classes to indicate layout.  That is little better than: `style="text-align: center"`.  Instead, use CSS classes to label the content:

```
<div id="messageBox" class="error-message">
```

Then in the CSS:

```
.error-message { text-align: center; margin: 1em; border: 1px solid red; }
```

Then if you decide you don't want to center the message text, you don't have to change dozens of JSPs to remove the "center" class from the message box.  The error message will always be an error message, but it may not always be centered.

Comment: Thanks, kevin. It was really just initial code that I had to quickly shove together having no Java background. Keeping it as a scriptlet SEEMS to be part of the requirement simply for organization purposes: the JSPs contain cosmetics. Non-cosmetic (the actual tracking of the sessions, data interchange) is handled by servlets. I'll look into moving them somewhere more appropriate, though. I especially appreciate comment #3; I will add this to my next 'thing to learn'.

Comment: Thanks again, Kevin. You've gone above and beyond. Ultimately any code I write during a prototyping phase will be under review by "real" Java developers; if I can make it closer to production-ready, all the better. I actually hadn't spotted that my markup has text-align: center in it; there's a CSS class already created and even at the prototype phase I don't typically use inline styles. I'd have to ask Past Greg why he did that. :-)